# What does this error mean "A slave with the same server_uuid/server_id as this slave has connected to the master;"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, master-slave-replication, multi-source

Upon searching for this, the main cause of this error is usually when using snapshots or cloning the machine. But I did not do this. I perform mysqldump --master-data=2 on the master then restore the dump on my slave server. Then start the slave on the position indicated on the outfile.

Any idea on what caused this? I am running a multi-source replica and this error is from just 1 source.

here is the complete error:

> Got fatal error 1236 FROM MASTER WHEN reading DATA FROM BINARY LOG: 'A slave with the same server_uuid/server_id as this slave has connected to the master; the first event 'VM1-bin.000006' at 641809774, the last event read from '/binlogdata/VM1-bin.000009' at 146836375, the last byte read from '/binlogdata/VM1-bin.000009' at 146836375.';

Answer (score 2):

Even if you `server_id` is different you may need to change the `server_uuid` which you can do manually in `my.cnf` or by deleting `$datadir/auto.cnf`, this file is created by MySQL when it stats and includes the server uuid.

So stop MySQL, remove the file, and start MySQL again.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of [server_uuid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_uuid) and [server_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_id) are for a MySQL source (a.k.a. master) server to close a zombie replica (a.k.a. slave) connection after a network error. (Also the server_uuid in MySQL or server_id in MariaDB go into the GTID to allow a replica to know which source each transaction came from.) When a replica connects, the source presumes that any old connection is a “zombie” that can be closed ([rpl_source.cc](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-cluster-8.0.31/sql/rpl_source.cc#L1095)).

According to the [server_uuid documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_uuid), server_uuid is automatically generated the first time that MySQL starts and saved to *data_dir*/auto.cnf (e.g. /var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf). So some causes of duplicate auto.cnf might be:

- Did you restore the datadir from a backup?
- Did you create a Debian or Ubuntu image with mysql-server preinstalled, and then run multiple instances of it as replicas? Both the [postinst script](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-cluster-8.0.31/packaging/deb-in/mysql-packagesource-server.postinst.in#L115) and the mysql.service [ExecStartPre script](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-cluster-8.0.31/packaging/deb-in/extra/mysql-helpers#L159) run `mysqld --initialize-insecure` which puts the server-uuid in /var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf.

To fix the latter issue, for my mysql read replicas, I created a debian image with mysqld installed but without the datadir /var/lib/mysql/ initialized using this snippet:

```sh
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/
curl --fail --location https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb --output /tmp/mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i /tmp/mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb
apt-get update

# disable starting mysql.service at install time
echo disable mysql.service | sudo tee /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/01-disable-mysql-while-installing.preset
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server
sudo rm /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/01-disable-mysql-while-installing.preset
# re-enable mysql service; it will start at the next boot
sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
# delete the datadir created by mysql-server postinst;
# mysql.service’s ExecStartPre will recreate it
rm -r /var/lib/mysql
```

Looking at the MySQL 8.0.31 source, this error may also be sent after a group replication error or when rejoining group replication, but I have not tested that (tracing duplicate_slave_id in the source [rpl_binlog_sender.cc](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-cluster-8.0.31/sql/rpl_binlog_sender.cc#L466-L471).

Answer (score 0):

You must have a different value in the my.cnf on each server in a replication setup.  `server_id` must be different on each machine, else replication will be trying to go in a loop.